# Can I specify an external WMS service with THREDDS?

Tags: wms, xml, thredds

I know that when you use THREDDS, you can specify the internal ncWMS-based WMS service thusly at the top of your catalog:

```xml
 <service name="wms" serviceType="WMS" base="/thredds/wms/"/>
```

The only problem is that the internal WMS service doesn't work for our unstructured (e.g. triangle based grids).

Is there a way to specify an external WMS service here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expose an external WMS service (such as a 3rd party WMS or a
standalone installation of NcWMS) through TDS and also included in ISO
metadata, one can do this:

Define a service tag pointing at your external WMS server outside of
the typical compound services.

```xml
<service name="agg" base="" serviceType="compound">
  <service name="odap" serviceType="OpenDAP" base="/thredds/dodsC/"/>
  ...
</service>

<service name="ncwms_in.usf.fvcom.ike.ultralite.vardrag.nowave.2d"
         serviceType="WMS"
         suffix=""
         base="http://ec2-107-21-136-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/wms/in_usf_fvcom_ike_ultralite_vardrag_nowave_2d/" />
```

Inside of your dataset tags: use the  tags to define each service:

```xml
<dataset name="FVCOM - IKE - Ultralite - Variable Drag - Waves - 2D"
         ID="in.usf.fvcom.ike.ultralite.vardrag.wave.2d"
         urlPath="auto/in.usf.fvcom.ike.ultralite.vardrag.wave.2d">
    <access serviceName="ncwms_in.usf.fvcom.ike.ultralite.vardrag.wave.2d"
            urlPath=""/>
    <access serviceName="agg"
            urlPath="auto/in.usf.fvcom.ike.ultralite.vardrag.wave.2d"/>
 ...
</dataset>
```

The result is this (notice the external WMS link):

http://testbedapps-dev.sura.org/thredds/auto/inundation/inundation.html?dataset=in.usf.fvcom.ike.ultralite.vardrag.nowave.2d